# Best way to cling text to an element while also ignoring other div spacing?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to add some text after a `textbox` in-line.  I want it to be "attached" to the `textbox`, but I also want it to ignore any other `div`s that would try to force it to a new line.  The reason for this is my text boxes are somewhat close to the border of my wrapper `div`, and I want the text to not be affected by this wrapper `div` while still having its positioning relative to the `textbox`.

Is there a feasible way to do this?  I've tried using absolute positioning but that is making it tough to keep my page responsive.

**Edit:**

By request, here's the simplest example I can think of:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzaq5h4q/3/

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="textbox" />I want this text to stay inline, even past the wrapper!
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the text from wrapping by using `white-space: nowrap;` as it stops the text from breaking at the nearest whitespace when it runs out of space.

> **nowrap**
>
> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

By default `overflow` is set to `visible` on `#wrapper` which means content can spill out of it and still be shown.

> **visible**
>
> Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="textbox" />I want this text to stay inline, even past the wrapper!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't go past the `wrapper`, but you can wrap your text in `paragraph tags`.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zzaq5h4q/4/)

```css
p {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
input {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="textbox" />
  <p>I want this text to stay inline, even past the wrapper!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid going to a new line as this text in the real application will sometimes be there and sometimes not.  I'm essentially trying to make a text field that dynamically tells you whether a password and the confirmation match or not.  I have all that code worked out I just can't figure out the formatting I want.